# Properly storing copy/pasted text from a Microsoft Office document into a MySQL database

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I know that Microsoft office uses different encoding, what happen is when someone copy and paste texts from office to java text panel, it looks OK. But you then store it into MySQL database, and retrieve it. It suddenly become all kind of rubbish Latin characters.

I've tried to convert it to `utf-8` before store, but seems not work.

Wonder if there is anyway you can detect whether there is any latin characters in your text, so I can simply popup an alert to let user know before they save it.

Or, if there is anyway to disable the jTextField to only display everything in UTF-8 characters, so that when user copy and paste from word, it auto shows all the random codes instead of looking fine (at the beginning)

Example: With user entered something in word, and paste to jTextField, we pass the string directly(Note our sql database is `utf8_general_ci`), we then just fetch it to the JPanel, and we get:

> ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€
>   Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€š

Comment: Needs more details. How are you doing what exactly to store things in MySQL? Most likely you're simply not handling encodings correctly and it's not really related to Office copy-n-pastes. Does it work if you insert "funky characters", say Chinese, directly into your text field by hand?

Comment: I am, the database is set to be utf-8 as well. it's the way that when ppl copy from microsoft office to the JPanel, its encoding isn't utf8, but try convert them will get you all the random arabic characters

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues. First thing to do is find out what exactly has been written to the database. This is very easy with MySQL, just logon and run

```
SELECT HEX( column ) FROM table;
```

That'll give you the bytes that have been written to the table. You can then use [an app I wrote](https://github.com/chooban/Whats-That-Character-Set) for this very purpose. Take the hex string you got back from MySQL and [give it to the main class](https://github.com/chooban/Whats-That-Character-Set/blob/master/src/com/rosshendry/whatcharacterset/WhatCharacterSet.java) using the -b flag for bytes. You'll get a whole heap of output, and hopefully one of them will be what you had originally.

Once you know what it's being stored as, you have a starting point for debugging.